# Adding vue js dynamic form elements in a specific div

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following html and vue js code

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
                <td><strong>File</strong></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">

                <td><input type="text" v-model="row.title"></td>
                <td><input type="text" v-model="row.description"></td>
                <td>
                    <label class="fileContainer">
                        {{row.file.name}}
                        <input type="file" @change="setFilename($event, row)" :id="index">
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove</a>
                </td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When i click add, a table row is appended to the table body

```
 <div>
 <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
 </div>
```

The following are the methods for adding or removing a row

```
 methods: {
            addRow: function() {
                var elem = document.createElement('tr');
                this.rows.push({
                    title: "",
                    description: "",
                    file: {
                        name: 'Choose File'
                    }
                });
            },
            removeElement: function(index) {
                this.rows.splice(index, 1);
            },
            setFilename: function(event, row) {
                var file = event.target.files[0];
                row.file = file
            }
        }
```

Supposing i don't have a table and instead i am using a custom div,  how would i add the dynamic form to a specific div? All examples i have looked at are using createElement. How can i add the dynamic form to a specific div with a unique id?.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it

The html

```
    <div id="app">
   <div id="appendsurface"></div>
                <div v-for="(row, index) in rows">

                    <p><input type="text" v-model="row.title"></p>
                    <p><input type="text" v-model="row.description"></p>
                    <p>
                        <label class="fileContainer">
                            {{row.file.name}}
                            <input type="file" @change="setFilename($event, row)" :id="index">
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove</a>
                    </p>


                </div>
        <div>
            <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then the javascript

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                rows: []
            },
            methods: {
                addRow: function() {
                
                    var elem = document.createElement('div');
                    elem.className= "uniqueclass";

                    document.getElementById('appendsurface').appendChild(elem);  
                
                    this.rows.push({
                        title: "",
                        description: "",
                        file: {
                            name: 'Choose File'
                        }
                    });
                },
                removeElement: function(index) {
                    this.rows.splice(index, 1);
                },
                setFilename: function(event, row) {
                    var file = event.target.files[0];
                    row.file = file
                }
            }
        });
```

a working codepen https://codepen.io/gandalf8080/pen/poRMopG

Comment: Well I once did 10 input fields and hide them with v-if. Than according to user input I showed some of the input fields. Messy solution but different approach in the end.
Declare them and hide them.